# Creating a thumbnail of an image on an external server

Tags: django, image

Let's say that someone has a link to an external image: `www.externalsite.com/img/photo.jpg`

Now, people can hotlink that image on my forum using [img] tags. A feature that is widely supported on almost every forum. Since hotlinking has some disadvantages I want to know how I can make a thumbnail of the image, based on the given url. Something Google does in Google images.

My website is powered by Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `sorl.thumbnail`

In your templates you would use

```
{% thumbnail "http://external.server/img/image.png" "200x200" "scale" as im %}
    <img src="{{im.url}}" width="{{im.width}}" height="{{im.height}}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

you can also load from any context varable

```
{% for image in post.images %}
    {% thumbnail image.url "200x200" "scale" as im %}
        <a href={{image.url}}>
            <img src="{{im.url}}" width="{{im.width}}" height="{{im.height}}">
            ....
```